# TDD - Tests for introducing fields

Tags: tdd

I have some entity in my application called `Offer`. It has some fields like price, description and 3-4 more. As I'm learning TDD at the moment I don't want to introduce those fields without tests requiring them. The problem is field like `title` does not have any business meaning I can require so the test would be:

```
  user creates offer with title "xyz"
  assert that offer has title xyz
```

Is there any other way to introduce this kind of field. Should I even bother writing test for such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TDD you write tests for functionality. In your case the field itself is not important. You want that an instance keeps an specific value. A test for this could be:

```
sut.setProperty(value)

assertThat(sut.getProperty(), is(value)
```

But i would not write tests for this since there is no real functionality in it. You should have other tests which uses those properties and cover getter/setter for it. Exception is when getter/setter contains some kind of logic for example that a value has a upper limit.

Comment: Nice answer for a newbie. And you left enough room for me to add another answer. My vote for that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The core aspect here: good OOP focuses on *behavior* not, on *state*. In other words: at least when talking about object oriented languages, you prefer to not **expose** fields to the outside of your class.

Instead you think in terms of *behavior* - aka **methods**. In that sense, the other answer is correct; you would rather create getter/setters and verify those.

One disclaimer here: if possible, avoid setters. Rather make sure that your fields are assigned exactly once (by the constructor). In other words: strive to write immutable classes.

Coming back to my initial point: *how* a "field" is implemented is an internal implementation detail. That is something that you do not want the outside world to know about - so that you are free to change the implementation if required!